# RStudio console stuck - how to reset?

Tags: r, rstudio

Using Version 0.98.11013. Say I'm testing the following code in my script:

```
for (num in 1:5)
{
    # Print numbers from 1 to the loop variable
    print(1:num)
}
```

As I step over each line (using CTRL+R), I get the following output in the Console:

```
> for (num in 1:5)
+ {
+ # Print numbers from 1 to the loop variable
+ print(1:num)
+ }
[1] 1
[1] 1 2
[1] 1 2 3
[1] 1 2 3 4
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
>
```

Now, say I've made an error in my code and forgotten the closing brace `}`:

```
for (num in 1:5)
{
    # Print numbers from 1 to the loop variable
    print(1:num)

randomArray <- c(1:10)
# ...and the next line of the R script
```

Now the Console shows a `+` symbol for every line because it is looking for a closing brace. Someone new to R or RStudio may not be aware of this. Nothing I do gets output working again except closing and re-opening RStudio.

Is there a way to force the RStudio Console (or is it the R interpreter?) to "reset"?

Comment: Multiple people have downvoted because this question is not about programming. As the question is about a programming tool, it seems to fit perfectly into the SO remit, but if you think it belongs elsewhere please leave a comment rather than an anonymous downvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try click in the Console and then press the keyboard button `ESC`.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from `Esc` key that works in both RStudio and R console,

- `Ctrl + z` does work in R console (Windows)
- `Ctrl + c` does work in R console (Linux)(thanks to @Spacedman for pointing out the key for Linux)

In general, `RStudio → Tools → Keyboard Shortcuts Help` might come handy. Or just press `Alt + Shift + k`

Comment: Operating system dependent though. On Linux, hit Ctrl-C

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + l works in R console (Mac)

I recently for the first time had line numbers in the console where Ctrl + l did not clear everything, but ESC followed by Ctrl + l did.